# Is there a name for the test which is the simple statistical probability?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, terminology

Let's say I observe 10 people going in an alley and I find out 100 % are men. Since there are 50 % of men in population, I'd expect this to happen at random for every 1 in $$ \frac{1}{2^{10}}=0.00097 $$ cases. Is there a name for the test where this number would represent the p-value?

Comment: This is the p value of a one-sided exact binomial test.

Comment: To me this looks like a one-tailed exact binomial test. The p-value will be  $P(X \geq 10 \mid \pi_0 = 0.5) = 2^{-10}$. Since the number of successes is equal to the sample size, $P(X = 10) = P(X \geq 10)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test

Comment: to add the R code that produces 0.00097 as p-value: `binom.test(x=10,n=10,p=0.5,alternative="greater")`

Answer (score 1):

The test (first) mentioned by @MichaelM is implemented in R as `binom.test` as follows:

```
binom.test(10, 10, alt="g")

        Exact binomial test

data:  10 and 10
number of successes = 10, number of trials = 10, 
  p-value = 0.0009766
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7411344 1.0000000
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                      1
```

A similar test, using a normal approximation, is `prop.test`:

```
prop.test(10, 10, alte="g", cor=F)

        1-sample proportions test 
        without continuity correction

data:  10 out of 10, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 10, df = 1, p-value = 0.0007827
 alternative hypothesis: true p is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.787058 1.000000
sample estimates:
p 
1
```